# App Store Updates not working

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore

I'm running Mavericks (10.9.5) and it has been working without problems for months. Recently I can't install updates from the App Store. Since today, the App Store doesn't even show icons anymore. Also, when I open the iTunes store, almost no icons for store products (music, podcasts, etc.) are shown.

I've tried logging out of my account, restarting, etc. but to no avail. I'm seeing these error messages when I look in the console application:

When opening App Store:

```
com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: NSScanner: nil string argument (multiple times)
```

When trying to install an update:

```
com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[709]: ERROR: ITSExceptionHandler: {message:"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("#header").addClassName')", url:"https://se.itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/0414/da-storefront-autoinstallations.js", lineNumber:"361"}
```

When opening iTunes:

```
iTunes: Failed to create replacement string (multiple times)
iTunes: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue
```

This happens on a Macbook Air (Mid 2011). I have a second notebook (Macbook Pro, Mid 2012), everything works fine there.

UPDATE:
I tried reinstalling Mavericks using the Recovery-Volume, after downloading it runs for approx. 30 minutes, then stops without having reinstalled. This is very weird!

Any ideas on what could be the reason for all this? Where can I continue digging?

Answer (score 1):

You can try open the Terminal and this command :

```
killall softwareupdated
```

Then go with the Finder to Maj+CMD+ G : /Library/Updates and delete "index.plist" and "ProductMetadata.plist".

Then manually update app Store with this command :

```
softwareupdate -i
```

Answer (score 0):

First things I'd do would be

1. Run Disk Utility, check permissions & verify/repair disk
2. Grab the combo updater for 10.9.5 & re-install http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760

Comment: Couldn't even reinstall without erasing startup volume... Which is what I've done now. Thanks anyway!